# Where are we use LinkItemNotFoundUrl setting

Tags: sxa

We have a setting under `Sitecore.config` file.

```
<setting name ="LinkItemNotFoundUrl" value ="/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx" />
```

Could someone assist me real time scenario when this setting will hit the page?

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below steps to test this scenario :-

- Create two Sitecore items in Content Editor, one is **Page 01** and second is **Page 02**. On **Page 01** in the Content Editor add content in rich text field and
  create an anchor tag on **Page 2** text for **Page 02** item.

[image]

- Now , open this page in Experience Editor. You can see the anchor tag on Page 2.
- Delete Page 02 in Content Editor and it will open dialog box, select **Leave links** option.

[image]

- When, you will open Page 01 in Experience editor and click on the link then `LinkItemNotFoundUrl` setting will call and will open `/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx` page.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding here is the use of this field.

`linkItemNotFoundUrl`: The URL to redirect to if an item being linked to is not found.

**Default value**: if not specified, the value of the `LinkItemNotFoundUrl` setting in the `<settings>` section is used.

Initially, You don't need to extend the processor, there are settings in the `Sitecore` section of `config` to handle these. Update these values to point to the correct path. This can be a Sitecore item path, e.g. `/errors/404` as long as that item exists in Sitecore.

Alternatively, You may need to create a processor that will handle this request. Use this article for more details on how to create a processor.

http://sitecoreblog.navavayas.com/Blog/35/Better-way-of-handling-sitecore-404-pages-

Comment: is that link not active?

Answer (score 1):

According to Sitecore documentation:

```
/// <summary>Gets the URL to redirect to, if an item is not found.</summary>
/// <value>Default value: "/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx"</value>
/// <remarks>
/// If a request for a non-existing item comes in on the
/// web site, the request is redirected to the url pointed to
/// by this setting.
/// </remarks>
public static string LinkItemNotFoundUrl => Settings.SettingsInstance.Core().LinkItemNotFoundUrl;
```

What is interesting though, looks like it's only used in obsolete `DynamicLink` class methods in Sitecore 10.X, so it looks like it should not be used at all in any new Sitecore implementations.

Comment: Do you have any example to test this as I am working on some scenario?

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

While generating an Item URL for non-existing culture version, It generates the URL of page specified at `LinkItemNotFoundUrl` configuration setting.
The configuration defines the page, which does not respect the language in Multi-culture websites.

As per, example of Build an Item URL; URL generation respects `culture/language` based on the `LinkBuilder/UrlBuilder` configuration.
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/build-item-and-media-urls.html

Error URL generation may also, need to respect `LanguageEmbedding` and Language Location configuration.
Sitecore registered a feature request for the product so that it can be considered for future implementation. To track the future status of this request, please use the **reference number 541614**.